# Filename length limit for ctp file in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is there any limit set on the length of ctp file name in cakephp?
In my case i created a file with more than 40 characters name.But it is not rendered.I even  used

`$this->render('ajax_get_student_assignments_by_course_id');`

But again it is not rendered .

Answer (score 1):

### No

There is no limit imposed by CakePHP.

```
$ cat views/pages/ajax_get_student_assignments_by_course_id.ctp 
MyFile's contents 
<?php die;
$ curl http://example.dev/pages/ajax_get_student_assignments_by_course_id
MyFile's contents
$
```

Which probably means there's an entirely different (fatal) error - which will probably show up in the error log.